# What is a LaunchAngel?

Tags: macos

While working with Launchctl on MacOS I am periodically suggested to use a "Launch Angel".

I can find nothing in the man pages or online about it.

Intentionally non-specific to trigger the response message:

Command

```
launchctl bootstrap gui/loggedInUserID /Library/LaunchAgents/com.anything.app.plist
```

Repsonse

```
Unrecognized target specifier.
Usage: launchctl bootstrap <domain-target> [service-path, service-path2, ...]
        --angel
                Bootstrap the plist as a LaunchAngel
<service-target> takes a form of <domain-target>/<service-id>.
Please refer to `man launchctl` for explanation of the <domain-target> specifiers.
```

Comment: Newer macos versions have `LaunchAgent`. What macos version do you have ?

Comment: This is happening on Ventura